# Why isn't ask defined directly on ActorRef for Akka?

Tags: scala, akka

I am learning about Akka, and while exploring the API, I came across something kind of curious (at least to me). The `tell` function is defined directly on the ActorRef class. However, the `ask` function is declared in the AskSupport trait. I can't think of any good reasons why they needed a seperate trait for `AskSupport` rather than including `ask` in the API for ActorRef (and `?` in the API of ScalaActorRef). Would anyone care to enlighten me on the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Actor docs gives the author's reasoning:

> The ask pattern involves actors as well as futures, hence it is offered as a use pattern rather than a method on ActorRef

The ask pattern includes Future extensions, not just ActorRef extensions. In particular, if you look through the akka.pattern docs, you'll note `PipeToSupport` and `PipeableFuture` beyond the extensions to Akka objects.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Akka Docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/actors.html):

> There are performance implications of using `ask` since something
>   needs to keep track of when it times out, there needs to be something
>   that bridges a `Promise` into an `ActorRef` and it also needs to be
>   reachable through remoting. So always prefer `tell` for performance,
>   and only `ask` if you must.

Given this, it makes sense that you'd want to subtly discourage the use of `ask` by requiring users to explicitly import the facility.  This has the added benefit of reducing bloat in the `ActorRef` API.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Akka is based on the Erlang system of actors and I believe that `tell` is the only facility to communicate between actors in that system.  I imagine that the Akka guys want to keep the `ActorRef` in Akka as similar as possible to it's Erlang analog.

One other thing to keep in mind is that `ask` is simply a pattern of using a `tell` and then setting up a `Future` and temporary actor to handle the responding `tell` to make it look like a native request/response process.  But under the hood, it's really just two actors telling back and forth.  It's a convention of using `tell`s to create the appearance of request/response and that's why it's setup as a pattern in Akka that can be pulled in when needed as opposed to being part of the `ActorRef`.

Comment: That's true of the (now deprecated) Scala actors.  It's also true that Akka was *originally* named scala-otp and was inspired by the Erlang equivalent.  However... Akka's model has now diverged significantly from Erlang's; most notably, with respect to the handling of nested receives.  Akka also incorporates a number of concurrency patterns above and beyond actors.  Because of this, it's no longer strictly correct to draw analogies between the two implementations.